# AS3: Actions inside dynamically added movie clip not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, addchild

I have a very strange problem with a simple test I'm trying to do in AS3.

I have two functions on my first frame:

```
function function1 ():void {
    trace ('function1 executed');

    mc.gotoAndStop (2);

    function2 ();
}

function function2 ():void {
    trace ('function2 executed');

    var test_mc:test_lib = new test_lib ();
    addChild (test_mc);
}
```

As you can see, function1 changes the frame on "mc" and also calls function2, which adds a child movie clip from the library in the stage.

Function1 is called from inside another simple movie clip, on the 60th frame, like so:

```
Object(parent).function1 ();
```

This child movie clip that is added, is just a black square with a trace action on it's first frame.

The trace action should work as soon as the child is added, but it's not.
However, if I remove or comment the line `mc.gotoAndStop(2)`, the trace action works normally. It also works if I put the `mc.gotoAndStop(2)` AFTER I call the function2.

I can't see why this is happening.

This happened on a larger project that I was working so I decided to isolate the problem on a new file, and create the example above. This is very weird.

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work but I know how to fix this. Call `function2` with delay (ex. 1 ms). `setTimeout(function2, 1);` It works!

Comment: Weird, huh? As I said, it works too if I just call the mc.gotoAndStop(2) AFTER the function2(); I just wanted to know why this is happening. Seems like a bug to me.

Answer (score 1):

try shifting your function2 inside mc frame 2.

main timeline:

```
function function1 ():void {
    trace ('function1 executed');

    mc.gotoAndStop (2);
}
```

in mc -> on frame 2

```
trace ('function2 executed');
var test_mc:test_lib = new test_lib ();
addChild (test_mc);
```

You will have to slightly amend the code inside `mc` using  `.root`

Comment: That's a possible solution. But I can already make it work by calling function2() before the mc.gotoAndStop(2), as I said. I just wanted to know why is this happening...

Answer (score 0):

What is *mc*? If *mc* is the *MovieClip* that contains both of your functions, then your code obviously cannot work because after you *gotoAndStop(2)*, you can no longer call *function2()* because *function2()* does not exist on the second frame.

Comment: mc is not movie clip with the functions. It's just a simple movieclip on the stage.